# Sabre json api bargain finder max response as gzip

Tags: sabre, sabredav

I am trying to get the response from bargain finder as compress. I am setting the "Accept-Encoding": "gzip" but the response is coming as simple json file not compressed.

Response header contains following information also.
'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Server': 'Sabre Gateway'}

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of compressed responses:

1. **Accept-Encoding: gzip**
   This is done by HTTP, you don't see the compression in the response, because, as far as I know it is the protocol that decompresses it.
   As you can see in the HTTP header (of the response), there's one that statues *content-encoding: gzip* which means that it was returned zipped, if not you would likely see json.
   The reason why I say "likely" is that the endpoint seems to be configured to return the BFM response gzipped always, whether you request it (using the *Accept-encodding: gzip*) or not.
2. **"CompressResponse": { "Value" : true }**
   This element is available in the schema, but not covered in the service description because it does not seem to be available for REST, only for SOAP, I have tested it.